# How to change the size of some elements of WPF DatePicker

Tags: xaml

I'm writing a C# WPF application.
In a window i put two DatePicker objects: I was able to enlarge the font of the calendar and enlarge the image icon.

I also need to enlarge the font of the two first lines of the calendar (month + year) and the row of the days of week (see the image ..).

[image]

I created a copy of the style for DatePicker control but I do not identify the element to change in it.
I defined a new setter for CalendarDayButton, CalendarDayButton, CalendarItem to set font to 36px but I dont see the result.

How can achieve that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you a way using the `VisualTreeHelper`.

First, you need to have a way to search controls through the VisualTree.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

        if (child is T childAsT)
        {
            yield return childAsT;
        }

        foreach (T grandChild in FindChildren<T>(child))
        {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the `DatePicker`'s `CalendarOpened` event handler, we can find the `Popup` and controls inside it. The `Popup.Child` is a `Calender` control, which has 50 `TextBlock`s inside it. The items with index 1 to 7 are the `TextBlocks` for the days of the week.

```cs
private void DatePickerControl_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (FindChildren<Popup>(DatePickerControl).FirstOrDefault() is not Popup popup)
    {
        return;
    }

    double fontSize = 20;

    if (FindChildren<Button>(popup.Child)
        .Where(x => x.Name == "PART_HeaderButton")
        .FirstOrDefault() is Button headerButton)
    {
        headerButton.FontSize = fontSize;
    }

    if (FindChildren<TextBlock>(popup.Child) is IEnumerable<TextBlock> textBlocks)
    {
        int targetChildIndex = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            TextBlock dayOfTheWeedTextBlock = textBlocks.ElementAt(targetChildIndex);
            dayOfTheWeedTextBlock.FontSize = fontSize;
            var text = dayOfTheWeedTextBlock.Text;
            targetChildIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (FindChildren<Grid>(popup.Child)
        .Where(x => x.Name == "PART_YearView")
        .FirstOrDefault() is Grid yearViewGrid)
    {
        foreach (CalendarButton calendarButton in FindChildren<CalendarButton>(yearViewGrid))
        {
            calendarButton.FontSize = fontSize;
        }
    }

    if (FindChildren<Button>(popup.Child)
        .Where(x => x.Name == "PART_NextButton")
        .FirstOrDefault() is Button nextButton)
    {
        nextButton.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1.5, 1.5);
        nextButton.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh my, is it not possible to access via xaml code ??

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. The problem now is the font of the central window when it shows year or month .. the font is still little.

Comment: That is a `Grid` named *PART_YearView* and has 12 `CalendarButton`s for each month. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry again but, what about the next/prev arrows' size? Are they a bitmap?

Comment: I found the 'PART_NextButton' but incrementing its width and Height size, the arrow does not enlarge.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), those arrows are `Path` elements and you can't change their sizes by changing the `FontSize`. I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I saw in another doc that they was an image ... Thanks!